adobe animate- video2 automatically after video1?
I'm a newbee in Adobe animate. Years ago I made some flash stuff, but I'm quite new to HTML5/canvas. I come from years of 2d/3d stuff.
So what I sucessfully got to do was making buttons on a movie (imported mp4 video instance). These buttons lead to new movies (video instance) that I did mostly with the HTML5/canvas code snippets. Everything works so far.
But, what I want now is that a button first plays a movie (video instance) and automatically plays a second movie (video instance) afterwards.
I'm in frame 20, I have a canvas.style.zIndex = "1"; and a this.stop() and so I tried some "codeing"... once with event.COMPLETE, one with comparing currentFrame to totalFrames and one with delaytime of 3 seconds (length of my second film...75 frames), but no code is correct and working in any way.
I'm super happy until now and I hope that I can get this final thing done. Otherwise I would cut these 2 film packs together in a cutting program. But I would be also super interested why all codes don't work.
It would be super if some specialist could look over the codes why they don't work.

// Play the first video
this.filmZoo1.play();

// When the first video ends, start the second video
this.filmZoo1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playSecondVideo);

function playSecondVideo(event:Event):void {
this.filmOmn.play(); // Play the second video
}


// Add an event listener to movie1 to listen for each frame update
this.filmZoo1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkMovie1Complete);

function checkMovie1Complete(event:Event):void {
    // Check if movie1 is on the last frame
    if (filmZoo1.currentFrame == filmZoo1.totalFrames) {
        // Remove the event listener to stop checking once movie1 finishes
        this.filmZoo1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkMovie1Complete);
        
        // Start movie2 after movie1 finishes
       this.filmOmn.play();  // Play movie2
    }
}


import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

// Assuming you know the duration (in milliseconds) or number of frames the MovieClip runs
var duration:Number = 3000;  // Example duration in milliseconds (3 seconds)

// Create a Timer with the specified duration
var finishTimer:Timer = new Timer(duration, 1); // 1 indicates it will only run once

finishTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onMovieClipFinish);
finishTimer.start();

function onMovieClipFinish(event:TimerEvent):void {
    this.filmOmn.play();
    trace("MovieClip finished after " + duration + "ms.");
    // Optionally, perform other actions here, like playing another MovieClip
}

What I want is that a button first plays a movie and automatically plays a second movie afterwards. So very simple task as I thought, but I found nothing matching in code snippets.
